# Find the sum of a column with unknown numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, matrix

How can I find out the sum of a column of a matrix if I don't know the numbers in that column but I have to give the numbers with JOptionPane??

Answer (score 2):

Assume `double[] numbers` is the list of decimal numbers.

```
double[] numbers = new double[10]; // 10 doubles
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
{
    sum += numbers[i];
}
```

To get a number from a JOptionPane, use `Double.parseDouble()` to convert the String to a double.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
double d = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Comment: thank you but it's not showing any output...I mean I enter the numbers but the sum doesn't show up :/ anyways thanks for your help...

Comment: Of course it doesn't show anything. I'm just handing you the tools, you have to combine. Try something with these things I gave you.

Comment: that's what I'm saying...I put that on my code and still it's not working but thanks again...